# Integration of some weird function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am just wondering, is there a closed form for such integral? I am thinking along the lines of polar substitution but I cannot exactly figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}}  e^{\large{-\frac{z^2}{2[{x^2+(1-x)^2]}}}}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

*[Additional] Now, I tried this (as commented by User45878).

Suppose I let $$f(z)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}}  e^{\large{-\frac{z^2}{2[{x^2+(1-x)^2]}}}}\ \mathrm{d}x$$ From which I get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(z)=\frac{-z}{x^2+(1-x)^2}f(z)$$
So that 
$$\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{-z}{x^2+(1-x)^2}$$
Am I going on the right track, or it will just lead me nowhere? I am not so sure how to apply the "differentiation under integration" technique.

Comment: did you try Maple, Mathematica, or WolframAlpha?

Comment: I tried with Wolfram Alpha. But it said that computation time exceeded.

Comment: Are you sure that there should be a $z$ in the exponent? If you are you could try [differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) under the integral sign with respect to it.

Comment: Yes there is a $z$ in it. Anyways, it s a constant with respect to the integration operation, so does it matter?

Comment: For $z=0$ we have $I=\sqrt2\cdot\text{arcsinh }1$.

Comment: Yes, I got that one too. But what if $z\neq0$? How do I solve it?

Comment: What you get when you differentiate under the integral sign should be some sort of ODE which is independent of $x$

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast your differentiation under the integral sign is wrong, $f(z)$ cannot depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By noticing that $2\left(x^2+(1-x)^2\right)=(2x-1)^2+1$ we have:

$$I_z=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}}  e^{\large{-\frac{z^2}{2[{x^2+(1-x)^2]}}}}\,dx = \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{1+y^2}\right)\,dy,$$

$$I_z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{1}{u\sqrt{(1-u)}}e^{-z^2u}\,du=\sqrt{2}\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}e^{-z^2u^2}\,du,$$

$$I_z = \sqrt{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\exp\left(-z^2\sin^2\theta\right)}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\exp\left(-z^2\cos^2\theta\right)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta.\tag{1}$$
By differentiating with respect to $z$ we get:
$$\frac{dI_z}{dz}=-2\sqrt{2}\,z\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos\theta\cdot\exp\left(-z^2\cos^2\theta\right)\,d\theta,$$

$$\frac{dI_z}{dz}=-2\sqrt{2}\,z\,e^{-z^2}\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos\theta\cdot\exp\left(z^2\sin^2\theta\right)\,d\theta.\tag{2}$$
By taking the Taylor series of the exponential function we can write:
$$\frac{dI_z}{dz}=-2\sqrt{2}\,z\,e^{-z^2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{k!}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos\theta\sin^{2k}\theta\,d\theta,$$
$$\frac{dI_z}{dz}=-2\,e^{-z^2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{2^{k}(2k+1)k!}=-2e^{-z^2}\cdot\int_{0}^{z}e^{w^2/2}dw.\tag{3}$$
Since a rescaled [Dawson integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) appears in the RHS, $I_z$ does not have a closed form in the common sense. Anyway, by taking derivatives in $(3)$ we get that $I_z$ satisfies the differential equations:
$$\frac{d^2 I_z}{dz^2}+2z\frac{dI_z}{dz}+2e^{-z^2/2}=0,\tag{4}$$
$$\frac{d^3 I_z}{dz^3}+(2+2z^2)\frac{d^2 I_z}{dz^2}+(2+z)\frac{dI_z}{dz}=0.\tag{5}$$
By $(1)$, an expression for $I_z$ is given by:
$$I_z=\sqrt{2}\,e^{-z^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{k!}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin^{2k}(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \sqrt{2}\,e^{-z^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{k!}\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{u^{2k}}{1-u^2}du,\tag{6}$$
where:
$$\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{u^{2k}}{1-u^2}du=\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-u^2}-\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u^2}\right)du,$$
$$\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{u^{2k}}{1-u^2}du=\log(1+\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^j(2j-1)}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{j>k}\frac{1}{2^j(2j-1)}.\tag{7}$$
By writing $e^{-z^2}$ as a Taylor series and by regarding $(6)$ as a Cauchy product we get:
$$I_z = 2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}(1-u^2)^{2n-1}du,\tag{8}$$
in which we see values of the incomplete Beta function, as already pointed by user121049.

Answer (score 0):

Could do a power series in z. The coefficients are nasty looking incomplete beta functions (courtesy of Wolfram Alpha), but maybe they simplify.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? :|

Comment: Expand exponential in powers of $z^2$ which gives you a series of integrals like $\frac{1}{(x^2+(1-x)^2)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}$. These integrals can be done. I doubt that you can sum them, but at least it will give you small z behaviour. PS this is my first post so apologies if my Latex falls over.

Comment: @user121049 It would be better to add that to your answer.